# what are the possible reason's can causes PHP process terminate before finishing it?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, optimization, xampp

i am working Performance Optimizations of an report (CodeIgniter) due to huge process load or memory usage , i am not exactly sure about, it got stopped during report generation

it is using XAMPP and MySQL

what are the possible reason's can causes  PHP process terminate before finishing it ?

except exceeding memory limit and max_execution_time as i am already handling this reasons and quit minimized them by using

```
    $this->db->save_queries = FALSE;
    $this->db->cache_off()  ;
    ini_set("memory_limit", -1);
    ini_set("max_execution_time", -1);
```

please aware me if their is any unwanted effect of using them and any other efficient way's

Comment: If you are using CI, have you tried turning on the `$config['log_threshold'] = 0;`? this will create a log file for you showing the errors and other detailed information. This can be set in the config.php file.

Comment: The unwanted effect is that a single query could take down your entire server. Rather 100 slightly unhappy customers then 1 happy and 99 totally unhappy.

Comment: use cron for long running processes, apache don't handle these very well.